# master and stable branches, which one are actually stable?

Tags: git, github, release, release-management, git-workflow

Some projects have master and stable branches. When bug is found in project it's fix goes into master branch, so now master branch is more stable than "stable" branch. Question is, what branch should I use to get stable release?

Comment: Ask the owner of the repository. "stable" might just mean "this is stable and intended for release" whereas master could mean "this has already been released". But again, you must ask the owner of the repository what meaning they attribute to the branches. There is no fixed answer that anyone can provide here because it depends.

Comment: I asked the owner, he said that fixes would be backport back to "stable" branches as well, so stable branches are actually having all fixes the master branch have. So it's settled, thanks.